# Looking for Java clever task scheduler and executor

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm looking for a Java task scheduler that has a specific feature set before I stumble into developing it myself.

It's not so much of a scheduler, but a logic gate that determines which tasks in a set (*T*) can be executed now (e.g. passed off to a ThreadPoolExecutor) and which tasks must wait for some future condition.

This is an example of what I would like to implement:  Consider various attributes that might be associated with each task:

- Foo: Foo tasks can only be executed one at a time, so *T.foo2* cannot start until *T.foo1* has completed, regardless of how much execution capacity there is.
- Bar: Bar tasks have no concurrency limitations, so the scheduler can throw caution to the wind and blast *T.bar1* through *T.barN* directly into the execution queue.
- If a task is marked as having attributes **Foo** *and* **Bar**, then the **Foo** attribute would take precedence with respect to scheduling.

Simple, right ?

Anyone know of such a framework ?

Thanks !

//Nicholas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you want to use separate executors.  You could have a `newFixedThreadPool(1)` for `Foo` and then `Bar` would use `newCachedThreadPool()` if you really wanted to make it unlimited threads.

Then you would have some wrapper object so you could `submit(Foo foo)`, `submit(Bar bar)`, or `submit(Object obj)` which would test for `Foo` or `Bar` and submit it to the right executor.  Something like:

```
public class FooBarExecutor {
    private ExecutorService fooExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
    private ExecutorService barExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public <T> Future<T> submit(Foo foo) {
        return fooExecutor.submit(foo);
    }

    public <T> Future<T> submit(Bar bar) {
        return barExecutor.submit(bar);
    }

    public <T> Future<T> submit(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Foo) {
            return submit((Foo)obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Bar) {
            return submit((Bar)obj);
        } else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              "Object should be either Foo or Bar");
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that `Foo` and `Bar` both implement `Runnable` or `Callable`.  I also doubt I got the generics right but you get the idea.

Comment: Hey, fast response Gray ! I like the idea of designating pools configured for the concurrency of the attribute. However, the attributes I invented would be arbitrary, so in my imagination, the framework would provide a means of declaratively defining what the constraints are for each named attribute. Under the covers, though, it might do exactly what you outlined after dynamically whipping up the required constructs.

Comment: @Nicholas Yeah that's a lot harder.  You could have `Foo` and `Bar` both implement some sort of `createExectuorForMe()` interface method and then you could keep a concurrent map of class to `ExecutorService` but maybe that's too complicated.  When you submit an object, it looks up the class and if no executor, it calls the `createExectuorForMe()` method on the object or something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be overkill for your case, but *the* task scheduler for Java applications is [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I thought about Quartz, but I do not remember it having this sort of functionality. It's been a while though. I will go back and take a look at the latest.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/files/documentation/Quartz-2.1.x-Documentation.pdf) does have extension points, which might help allow making these kind of decisions on job processing. Look at:

`public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context)`

in particular.